# Read specific column and get other columns with csv or pandas module

Tags: pandas, csv

I'm trying to parse through a csv file and extract the data from only specific columns by using pandas.

Example csv:

```
Name | Address | City |

ABCD | Address5 | City7 |
EFGH | Address2 | City5 |
IJKL | Address6 | City5 |
```

I'm trying to extract all of values in column "Address" based on the value in "Name" column. So for ABCD will get Address5, EFGH will be Address2, IJKL will be Address6, and so on.

```
g = df.groupby('Name)[['Address']]
for Name in g:
    print(Name)
```

Is this code right?

Comment: What do you mean? The csv already has the right names and addresses on the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Toy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Name": ["ABCD", "EFGH", "IJKL"],
        "Adress": ["Adress5", "Adress2", "Adress6"],
        "City": ["City7", "City5", "City5"],
    }
)

# Extract values
adresses = {name: adress for name, adress in zip(df["Name"], df["Adress"])}

print(adresses)
# Outputs
{'ABCD': 'Adress5', 'EFGH': 'Adress2', 'IJKL': 'Adress6'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro, I will try it. And if this work then I will accept your answer